# Date convert from one string to another

Tags: java

So I'm sort of a newbie when it comes to java and program in general but I have no idea how to start this. I need to make a program where the User enters any date date like a String (01/21 or 1/21) and the output will come out as the String January 21. I also need to make two different exceptions. A MonthException if the month entered is not between 1 and 12 and a DayException if the day entered is less than zero or above the maximum days for that specific month.

Comment: try something and ask where you face challenge...start with a main method and see if you can create a method to take string input.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a computer, a compiler, an IDE? If you don't show you what you have done we have no idea what problem you are having.

Comment: I suggest you start with the first part of the problem "make a program where the User enters any date date like a String" This is one or two lines longer than a hello world program.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the Scanner object. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Usage:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner ("1/21");
int month = scan.nextInt();
int day = scan.nextInt();
if(month<1 || month>12)
  throw new Exception("Month value not correct");
if(day<1 ||day>31)
  throw new Exception ("Day value not correct");
System.out.println(month[month-1]+" "+day);
```

This is a very simple example where month is a string array containing the months in order. You could add more error checks such as checking if the integers are there in the string. The format of the string. etc.

Good luck

Comment: also use IDEs. They help for sure.